# How to read SSL data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm, ssl-certificate

I found a neat npm package that allows for this, called [sslinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sslinfo). However, this doesn't work for some reason (I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register`). Is there some other way I can read a site's SSL info via node.js/JavaScript/jQuery?

EDIT:

For future searchers! The accepted answer is correct, but what if you want some actionable data? This is what works for me (for now):

```
results.toString().match(/subject=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/CN=(.*)/)[1] // Subject Common Name
results.toString().match(/subject=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/O=(.*)\//)[1] // Subject Organization Name

results.toString().match(/issuer=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/CN=(.*)/)[1] // Issuer Common Name
results.toString().match(/issuer=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/O=(.*)\//)[1] // Issuer Organization Name
```

All this regex is ugly but, sslinfo wasn't cooperating. Also, I modified the answer code slightly to:

```
openssl.exec("s_client", {
  showcerts: true, connect: url // "url" is what I'm passing to the function
}, function (err, results) {
  console.log(
    // results.toString().match(/subject=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/CN=(.*)/)[1] // Subject Common Name
    // results.toString().match(/subject=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/O=(.*)\//)[1] // Subject Organization Name

    // results.toString().match(/issuer=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/CN=(.*)/)[1] // Issuer Common Name
    // results.toString().match(/issuer=\/(.*)/)[1].match(/O=(.*)\//)[1] // Issuer Organization Name
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sslinfo](https://github.com/iamthechad/sslinfo) is based on [openssl-wrapper](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-openssl-wrapper), so that can be used directly. E.g:

```
var openssl = require('openssl-wrapper');

var url = 'www.google.com:443'

return openssl.exec('s_client', {showcerts: true, connect: url }, function(err, buffer) {
    console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

Equivalent to this on the command line:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443
```

Comment: I had to do some extra stuff to my code to get this working, but it does! Would you know how to grab specific data from the `buffer`? Should I just parse `buffer.toString()`, or is there a quicker way?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to parse the data to extract the value you're expecting. Since this is what the sslinfo library was designed to do, try cloning their project and see if you can get it to run locally. If not, you can file a Github issue or submit a pull request. Probably worth a try before rebuilding it.

Comment: Cool, I'll investigate this later. For now, I'll accept your answer and comment with my own answer with details on how I got specific data. Thanks again! (: